In a very specific sense, what are the precise reasons why someone would not be able to verify whether or not their judgment is delusional?
I'm thinking of how people with dementia may not be aware that they have dementia, for example.
I'm also thinking about psychiatric syndromes associated with delusionality.
It seems like someone who is very rational would be constantly checking and analyzing all of their beliefs and even perceptions to gauge if they are reliable or not. But this implies an inner core of some self-consistent mental entity, an observing self, scrutinizing an outer layer of self, that of the self's consciously directed thoughts and consciously received perceptions.
A very rational person could become afraid that they are going insane, because they are perceiving things that they rationally know are not real or possible, or they may be entertaining thoughts which they know are irrational. Yet, the "inner self" knows that there is something wrong with the outer self.
It is interesting to wonder exactly, on the level of psychological mechanics, how a person can become fully delusional, especially when we consider a gradient from sanity to delusionality, or short moments of delusionality interspersed with sanity.
It seems to require some sort of epistemological analysis of something very particular happening to the "inner self" that I want to think more about. It is strange to consider that a delusional person would not be able to come to the conclusion that they are delusional, even if patiently guided in thinking through some counterarguments for the notions they are mentally entertaining. To some extent, it feels like it implies a loss of mental autonomy or self-awareness, which are very philosophical concepts, to me. It seems like some people would argue that real delusionality requires a "disintegration of self".

Metacognition
This thing is about ability to think about one's own thinking. In people with delusions, metacognitive processes can be disrupted, meaning they have difficulty reflecting on and evaluating their own thoughts and beliefs. This disruption prevents them from recognizing the irrationality of their delusions. Even if they are smart.
